# Two Column Lookup

Tags: excel, match, vlookup

I have a data set that I want to return an indexed column using two values: a year and a name.  Both these values are formatted to general (I also tried text) in my spreadsheet.

In one work sheet I have a like of people:

[image: sheet 1]

On the other, I have a table of Years, Names, and a number

[image]

I am trying to do a lookup on the joined year and name and return the given number in the second table. For instance 2013Andrew McCutchen would return 8.2, and 2014Andrew McCutchen would return 6.8.

Currently, I only get the #N/a value with the following"

```
 =INDEX('2006 Results'!C2:C556,MATCH($J$1&C3,'2006 Results'!$A$2&$B$556,0))
```

But, I know a certain value is in the table though because I have tested with an if statement to make sure my spelling is correct. Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: In my example, 8.1 (2013 number) would be in J3, under Year 1, and the 6.2 (2014 number) would be in K3,  However, in actuality, (2006) data will go in J3, and 8.1 will go under Year 8 or cell Q3.

Comment: @pnuts ah, sorry.  They are from a separate worksheet called "2006 Results".  The difference was I just made a quick example to show I have different years.  My dataset is  500+ rows with data going back to 2006.  Basically, I just made a example to screenshot better.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In your `match` expression, you are comparing one concatenated value `$J$1&C3` to another *single concatenated value* `'2006 Results'!$A$2&$B$556`. `Match` expects that second parameter to be a range rather than a single value.

In cases like this, where multiple criteria are required, I prefer to use `sumifs` rather than `index-match`, even though the intention is to return a single value. I think `=SUMIFS('2006 Results'!$C:$C,'2006 Results'!$A:$A,j$1,'2006 Results'!$B:$B,$c3)` will give what you need and should correctly copy to the other cells in that table.

Comment: Spectacular!  Great guess on the formula without the worksheet.  That makes sense, though I probably wouldn't have figured that out, but I'll definitely read up on sumifs

Comment: I assumed OP would complete the worksheet by adding years along row 1. If K1 contained "2014" then my formula would return 6.8 in K3.

Answer (score 0):

I would add a column to the left of the year column as column A to contain the following formula in cell A2 which refers to the year and name column:

`=$B2&$C2`

You can then use this column in a VLOOKUP formula on the people sheet.  Cell J3 would read as follows.  Copy this to all cells in the table body.

`=VLOOKUP(J$1&$C3,'TheYearSheet'!$A$1:$D$556,4,false)`

Job done.

Comment: About the answer above.  It will work if there is one row for each person and year combination.  if yo need to aggregate (ie SUM) it's a different story.   You could have provided slightly more detail in your question.

Comment: Ah,  sorry. I tried to show that the year and person combination were specific and a "key", but I guess I failed.  Thank you, though.

Comment: so did my answer work. please vote for it if it did!